# Linux update and now no more dual-boot menu on my Macbook, it just defaults to Linux

Tags: dual-boot

Title says it all. I installed a Linux update on my Macbook 2012 and now I can't access iOS. No rEFInd dual boot menu upon startup. Please help. All the tutorials I come across are for Windows DBs.

Comment: Which linux distro are you using?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu.